# Custom field names with COW

Tags: ocaml

Can I indicate custom field names to COW when serializing my data to JSON?

For example let's consider the following record type:

```
type t = {
  foo_bar : string;
} with json
```

I want `foo_bar` to be serialized as "foo bar" (' ' instead of '_').

With atdgen I would do the following :

```
type t = {
  foo_bar <json name="foo bar"> : string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json` syntax extension of `ocaml-cow` library provides only `of_json`, `to_json` and `json` syntactic constructions. So it doesn't allow you to indicate custom fields.